# Monodevelop bug - need help!

Tags: 12.04, monodevelop

Can someone at least give me an idea about who to ask about this?
Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 
Monodevelop locks up at the deploy dialog.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monodevelop mailing list would be good place to start:

http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monodevelop-list

Also you could try looking at open bugs and if you cant find one that matches then raise one. The bug tracker is here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/